# Create default code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like that every time I create a new java file, I have a default structure:

```
public class MyFirstJavaProgram {

   /* This is my first java program.
    * This will print 'Hello World' as the output
    */

   public static void main(String []args) {
      System.out.println("Hello World"); // prints Hello World
   }
}
```

How can I configure this in Visual Studio? (For me, this it´s better that file

Thank you!